# Access control configuration throws "App\Entity\PatientOrder object not found by the @ParamConverter annotation." error

Tags: symfony

I'm trying to configure access control to require authentication to access any page of my web app. But I get an error after setting the homepage route in my controller.

Security.yaml

```
access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

PatientOrderController.php

```
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="patient_order_index", methods={"GET"})
     * @param PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository
     * @return Response
     */
    public function index(PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository)
    {
        return $this->render('oncomine/patient_order/index.html.twig', [

            'patient_orders' => $patientOrderRepository->getPatientsWIthOrders()
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a routing error - the logout button was configured to point to app_logout however, it was hitting a route I had set up as /{id} before it got to my / route. So it was trying to show an entirely different page than I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

That is not an Access control throws the error.

In your **index** function there is a parameter "PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository". Symfony is trying to fetch the entity, but your route seems has no any IDs to use, so the @ParamConverter throws the error that it cannot find the entity.

Perhaps you have some IDs designed in your yml routing configuration, but then there is no **id** placeholder there, so the ParamConverter still throws the exception. If you use some kind of **patientId** as a placeholder in your router configuration, then you need to specify the mapping in your ParamConverter definition. See the [link](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html#doctrineconverter-options) for the reference

Comment: Thank you, I probably should have worded that differently. I get this error after configuring access control and trying to access the page while not being logged in. If disable it and log in, I dont get the error.

Comment: having ACL turned on and remove parameter **PatientOrderRepository $patientOrderRepository** from index function definition and **$patientOrderRepository->getPatientsWIthOrders()** replace with **[]** - will you have any errors?

Comment: I figured it out - I had two routes matching the logout URL - one was / and the other was /{id} - so it was calling the latter and throwing the error. Thanks for your help.